# spring jpa multiple entityManagerFactory, No qualifying bean of type

Tags: spring, jpa

I used multiple entitymanger in jpa

this is jpa repositories.

```
jpa:repositories base-package="com.wallet.repositories" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" 
    transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" 

    jpa:repositories base-package="com.cas.entity" entity-manager-factory-ref="casentityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="castransactionManager"
```

I got " No qualifying bean of type [com.cas.repositories.AccountRepository]"

This is accountrepo class

```
import com.cas.entity.Account;


public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Account> {

    @Query("select a from Account a where a.accountNo=?1")
    Account findByAccountNo(String accountNo);
}
```

Please see detail below

> ****org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CasAccountApi': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.cas.repositories.AccountRepository
>   com.cas.api.impl.AccountApi.accountRepository; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.cas.repositories.AccountRepository] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:301)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.embedded.JettyEmbeddedAdapter.start(JettyEmbeddedAdapter.java:67)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.launch(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:84)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.embedded.JettyEmbeddedLauncherMain.main(JettyEmbeddedLauncherMain.java:42)****

thanks in advance

Comment: You miss the Repository annotation

Comment: i added the Repository annotation. but no luck

Comment: try change the `jpa:repositories base-package="com.cas.entity"` to `jpa:repositories base-package="com.cas"`

Comment: Thanks a lot  amicoderozer. the problem is com.cas.entity instead of com.cas.repository

Comment: you are welcome! Pay attention to this, you could probably have problems with the transactionManager because you define as base package `"com.wallet.repositories"` but if you have entities in other packages Spring will not find them. Write your base package in that line like "com.wallet" to let Spring find all the beans you defined

Comment: got another problem.  as you can see there are two jpa:reppo below     <jpa:repositories xmlns="casreppos" base-package="com.cas.repositories"    entity-manager-factory-ref="casentityManagerFactory"
 transaction-manager-ref="castransactionManager" />

 <jpa:repositories  base-package="com.wallet.repositories"   entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
 transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"  />    problem is :only last jpa:reppo is working. for the first reppo: No qualifying bean of type

Comment: if i put com.wallet before com.cas reppo. then com.wallet reppo does not work